# Alternative to yad/Zenity for Unity

Tags: unity, 13.04, notification, alternative, zenity

In Ubuntu 13.04 yad and Zenity notification icons aren't showed in Unity.
I have written a script to use notification icon to alert me about lftp download progress.
Is there any alternative that it works in Unity?

Comment: Have you checked out notify-send?

Comment: I need a icon with menu or that I can pick in it to open the terminal with lftp. By other side, the notifications only are useful when I'm in front of PC.

Comment: I think alltray should be able to be used to put the yad/zenity window on the systray, but... after I tried it here, the window simply vanished and no systray icon for it showed, I think there have some incompatibility here, but may work for you? Also, may be, that feature could be asked for yad or even zenity.

Answer (score 2):

Include `notify-send "notification text"` as one of the lines in your bash script and a notification should pop up for a few seconds in the upper left corner of your screen.

Here's an example, a script I use in a chron job to back up my user data to a server at home where I use notify-send:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 #
 # First, we send a notification to the user that we've started.
 notify-send "rsync backup started"
 #
 # cd to home.
 cd ~/ 
 #
 # rsync my local home to rsync-marc on vulcan.
 rsync --exclude-from rsync-excluded-files.txt -azvv -e ssh ~/ xxxx@xxxxxxxxx.org:/media/marc/1d0b8719-f064-40a8-9589-4e65583788a8/marc/marc-rsync
 #
 # Last, we send a notification to the user that we've started.
 notify-send "rsync backup completed"
```

For more information on the many different parameters you could use, like always, `man notify-send`.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution isn't valid for me. I need a icon with menu or that I can pick in it to open the terminal with lftp.

Answer (score 1):

You can install an unity indicator that permit you to see icon-tray.

This one is pretty cool: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/on-demand-system-tray-for-ubuntu.html

Add this ppa:

> $ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/indicator-systemtray-unity
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install indicator-systemtray-unity

I reply 2 years after because it can help someone who fall here.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference ;)

Comment: for some reason, it crashed my cairo-dock, and couldnt restart it; only after removing that app, cairo-dock got back to work :(, but.. I already have tray icons, and I can have custom ones with ksystraycmd (but I cant find a way to click on it and open a menu or anything else, seems just a very simple icon indicator) and all-tray (still learning about it too).

Comment: Bumping this answer because the rcspam took time to update it and also to counter the downvotes.